# Grothendieck group and faithfully flat morpshim

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, kt.k-theory-and-homology, motivic-cohomology

For regular schemes $X$ and $Y$, and a faithfully flat morphism $f:Y \to X$, there is a flat pullback map of Grothendieck groups:
$$
f^*:K^0(X) \to K^0(Y).
$$

Is this map injective?

Comment: Even for finite etale morphisms, the pullback is typically not injective, e.g., for the "multiplication by $n$" isogeny of an Abelian variety to itself, the kernel of the pullback map on Picard groups is the $n$-torsion subgroup of the Picard group.

Answer (score 6):

It is not. For example, take a surjective morphism $f:\mathbb{A}^1\to\mathbb{P}^1$. $K^0(\mathbb{P}^1)=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$, while $K^0(\mathbb{A}^1)=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $f$ is not surjective (and so not faithfully flat)..

Comment: @DenisNardin There are many surjective maps of the kind I describe. For example take a two to one map from $\mathbb{P}^1$ to itself and remove a general point from the domain.